# Unlock the Sandbox

Tags: sandbox

I have encountered the problem that my Full Sandbox has been locked.

[image]

Kindly Help!!

Comment: You would have to contact your System Administrator or Salesforce Support, this is not in the scope of issues that would have answers here.

Answer (score 6):

**Locked Status**

The sandbox can’t be logged in to. This status is used when you have more sandboxes than your current licenses allow. This can happen if you let some or all your sandbox licenses expire. While the sandbox is locked, you can’t log in.
If your sandbox is in this state, contact your account manager to restore the expired licenses. You have 60 days to restore the licenses. If the licenses aren’t restored within 60 days, your sandbox is deleted.

Dav is correct, you need to contact your Account Manager for this to resolve.

[References](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_manage.htm)